# menu not showing up with tkinter in notebook

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, menu

I am not sure what is the problem, it's showing the menu, it shows the window with nothing within it

```
root = Tk()

menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Nuevo")
filemenu.add_command(label="Abrir")
filemenu.add_command(label="Guardar")
filemenu.add_command(label="Cerrar")
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Salir", command=root.quit)

editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
editmenu.add_command(label="Cortar")
editmenu.add_command(label="Copiar")
editmenu.add_command(label="Pegar")

helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="Ayuda")
helpmenu.add_separator()
helpmenu.add_command(label="Acerca de...")

menubar.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=filemenu)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Editar", menu=editmenu)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Ayuda", menu=helpmenu)

root.mainloop()
```

I am using python 3.8 in the jupyter notebook

Comment: Are you on a Mac? Also, is it _now_ showing up or _not_ showing up? The title and the question imply the menu _is_ showing up, making it not clear what the problem is.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes my bad I meant it's NOT showing. And yes I'm on Mac

Comment: Since you are on a Mac, did you look up to the top of the screen? Menus on the mac aren't in the window, they are at the top of the display.

Comment: oh my, you're right. Another q if you don't mind, is it normal that the kernel keeps loading as long as i don't close the window?